# How many ways to check username and password in api using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a test api. In this api, I am getting username and password from "curl -u username:password" after parsing. But I don't want to parse username and password in every api. Can we do that by any ways?
Example:

```
    app.get('/test',function(req,res){
        var header=req.headers['authorization']||'',        
        token=header.split(/\s+/).pop()||'',            // and the encoded auth token
        auth=new Buffer.from(token, 'base64').toString(),    // convert from base64
        parts=auth.split(/:/),                          // split on colon
        username=parts[0],
        password=parts[1];
"'+password+'"')
        if(username=="username" && password=="password"){
            res.status(200).json({
                "data":"/v1/test"
            });
        }else
        res.status(422).json({
            "error":"Invalid Username Password"
        });

    });*
```

Comment: Please read express documentation on [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can try express middleware.

```
const checkUsernameAndPassword = (req, res, next) => {
    var header=req.headers['authorization']||'',        
        token=header.split(/\s+/).pop()||'',            // and the encoded auth token
        auth=new Buffer.from(token, 'base64').toString(),    // convert from base64
        parts=auth.split(/:/),                          // split on colon
        username=parts[0],
        password=parts[1];
"'+password+'"')
        if(username=="username" && password=="password"){
            return next();
        } else {
            return res.status(422).json({
                "error":"Invalid Username Password"
            });
        }
};

app.get('/test', checkUsernameAndPassword, function(req,res){
    return res.status(200).json({ "data":"/v1/test" });
});
```